# How can I convert to Json Object to Json Array in Karate?

Tags: json, api, testing, bdd, karate

I want to convert *Json Object* to *Json Array* in Karate to use *'match each'* func.
I am getting to **('match each' failed, not a json array)** error when I use match each func with Json Object.

Here is My Json Object:

```
{
  { "a": "q"
    "b": "w",
    "c": "t"
  },
  { "a": "x"
    "b": "y",
    "c": "z"
  }
}
```

And here is what I need:

```
  [  
    {
     { "a": "q"
       "b": "w",
       "c": "t"
     },
     { "a": "x"
       "b": "y",
       "c": "z"
     }
   }
 ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach, using embedded expressions: https://github.com/intuit/karate#embedded-expressions

```
* def foo = { a: 1 }
* def list = [ '#(foo)' ]
* match each list == foo
```